# sum numbers in array where key is integer, php

Tags: php, arrays

my code:

```
foreach($comment as $key => $value) {

$total = $value['likes'];

echo "$key: $total\n"

}
```

Outputs:

> 0: 3 1: 18 2: 72 3: 0 4: 10 5: 0 6: 0 7: 0 8: 0 9: 0 10: 0 11: 19 12: 0 13: 0 14: 14 15: 19 16: 0 17: 0 18: 1

How do I sum all the values? The `array_sum` function gives a "warning: expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given".

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of all keys, all values or both? Please post your original array structure.

Comment: where are you calling array_sum? What values are you passing to it? I suspect that you are not passing your array to the function, and that is why it is giving you the above warning - but without seeing your actual code, it's hard to say what's wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array_sum is expecting a single dimension array. From the looks of your code you have a multi-dimensional array. Where $value is an array too.

You have the right idea with the total, but you have to add to your total like this `$total = $total + $value['likes']`, or the shorthanded version `$total += $value['likes']`:

```
$total = 0;

foreach($comment as $key => $value) {

    $total += $value['likes'];

    echo "$key: $total\n"

}

echo "My total is: $total";
```

Comment: that outputs: 0: 3 1: 21 2: 93 3: 93 4: 103 5: 103 6: 103 7: 103 8: 103 9: 103 10: 103 11: 122 12: 122 13: 122 14: 136 15: 155 16: 155 17: 155 18: 156

Comment: 156 being your total at the end

Comment: $total will contain 156, after you have done looping though the values. So you can use $total.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start off with a variable and keep adding to it if you want to do it this way.

```
$total = 0;

foreach($comment as $key => $value) {

   $total += $value['likes'];

}

echo "The sum is: " . $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($comment as $key=>$value) {
   $sum+=$value;
}

echo "Total: $sum";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a running total...

```
$total_likes = 0;

foreach($comment as $key => $value) {

    $total = $value['likes'];
    $total_likes += $total;

    echo "$key: $total\n"

}

echo "Total: $total_likes \n";
```